# Getting [$injector:modulerr] on a very simple page; can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very much a noob to Angular. And I'm getting an error that I just can't figure out (even after much Googling and fiddling around).

Here's my code (and [here it is on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYygMo)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="ergo">
    <title>Ergo</title>
</html>

<body ng-controller="ErgoController as ergo">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        ( function() {
            var app = angular.module( "ergo", [] );
            app.controller( "ErgoController", function() {
                // TODO
            } );
        } );
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The code above produces this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=ergo&p1=Error%3A%20…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A339)
```

([Here's a link](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=ergo&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.5%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dergo%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A334%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A483)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A218%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A146%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A428)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Lb%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A146)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A339) to the full URL from that error message.)

A few places on the web say that this can happen if the ngRoute module fails to load - it was formerly part of the Angular core, but was split out into its own module in 1.2.

Now, I'm not *using* ngRoute anywhere in this very simple page, so I don't understand how that could be the problem - but hey, I'll give it a shot. Here's my revised page (and [the corresponding CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwNLeK)) - I've added another  tag to load the ngRoute module, and also added 'ngRoute' as a dependency when instantiating my module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="ergo">
    <title>Ergo</title>
</html>

<body ng-controller="ErgoController as ergo">

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      ( function() {
          var app = angular.module( "ergo", ['ngRoute'] );
          app.controller( "ErgoController", function() {
              // TODO
          } );
      } );
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I still get the same error.

Help? I was doing pretty much the exact same thing the other day, and it was working fine. (Unfortunately, I don't have that code handy to examine.)

Secondary question: if you look at the errors in Chrome's JavaScript console after loading either of these pages, you'll see that the stack trace is full of references to this JavaScript file:

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.js`

Which is bizarre, because the URL I'm actually loading in my `<script>` tag is this:

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js`

(one URL contains `.min`; the other does not)

I looked at the network console to see whether angular.min.js was loading angular.js dynamically (for some bizarre reason), or maybe the `.min` URL was simply *redirecting* to the unminified version. Neither seems to be the case. So, why is the console showing references to a JavaScript file that, as far as I can tell, isn't even being loaded on this page?

Comment: Possible typo?. Did you forget to invoke the IIFE? `})();` It works otherwise. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEqOPy

Comment: Holy crap. I can't believe I missed that. I *knew* it was going to be something boneheaded. Thanks :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't invoking your function that sets up your angular app.

Try invoking that function and you should be good to go:

```
<script>
  (function() {
     var app = angular.module( "ergo", ['ngRoute'] );
     app.controller( "ErgoController", function() {
       // TODO
     } );
   })();
</script>
```

Comment: Yep; PSL noted that in the comments. I feel dumb now. Thanks.